# How does a Git repository works with a develop and master branch?

Tags: git

I'm new to Git and this is really confusing. I wanted to start off developing a web application on Git and so far I've been dealing with troubles that have kept me behind.

I've read [this blog](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) post on a successful branching model for Git. I was really interested in setting up something similar to this.

It says that the repository has 2 main branches called `master` and `develop`. So I went ahead and created a repository. However, to my surprise, the repository itself was the default `master` branch. How was I supposed to create a `develop` branch? Do I create it in the parent of the `master` branch? That would mean that the `develop` branch is outside the repository.

Am I getting something totally wrong here? Do I just ignore the fact that I'm creating two branches inside the master branch?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A branch is not a directory. It is a commit label that moves along with commits, like tag is a commit label that stays with a particular commit. You will not have anything "inside" the `master` branch, rather `master` and `develop` will both initially label the same commit.

Create the develop branch like so:

```
git branch develop
```

To clarify: let's say you have the initial commit A. It will be labeled as `master` branch.

```
git init

A [master]
```

If you make a new commit B, the branch label will move:

```
git commit -a

A -> B [master]
```

If you then branch into `develop`, the B will get the new label as well:

```
git branch develop

A -> B [master, develop]
```

If you commit on the `develop`, it will move, but `master` won't:

```
git checkout develop
git commit -a

A -> B [master] -> C [develop]
```

If you now commit on the `master`, the tree will fork:

```
git checkout master
git commit -a

A -> B -> C [develop]
     +--> D [master]
```

Meanwhile, you only have in your directory whatever the contents of your current commit is. Switch branches, and the directory contents change.

Comment: What if I have fresh changes in my master and then `git checkout develop`, will my uncommitted changes be lost when I switch to the branch?  Sorry, I'm a svn user.

Comment: @Harrison: If you have uncommitted changes, you shouldn't be able to `git checkout`. You should `git reset`, `git commit` or `git stash` before.

Comment: I'll look into that, thanks!  I'm just used to seeing a `branches` directory in my WC and editing branches and trunk simultaneously.

Answer (score 17):

The `master` branch is created by default; you can think of it like the "trunk" in other VCS systems. The `develop` branch used in the nvie branching model branches from `master`, presumably from the first commit.

The `develop` branch is a normal branch off of `master`.

`git branch develop` creates the `develop` branch.

In the nvie branching model, all development work is done on the `develop` branch and only merged to master and tagged there when the code is ready to be released. The typical workflow that many people use is just to commit all development to `master` and tag when the code is ready to be released.